# Interfacing with command line applications

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, pyautogui

I have a command line application, which I want to remotely control with another program I've yet to make. What is the best way to go about this?

In more detail:
I want to be able to read the text output of the application I want to control, and send commands to it from my other app via simple text input. Preferred language: python, c or c++

I tried to use winautogui, but couldn't find a way to implement it for CMD.

Comment: If you're on Linux there's a nifty program called [expect(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) which can automate command-line programs. It uses TCL and regexes. There's also a Perl module called [Expect.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) but I don't know if it works natively on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found a python version of expect for windows called [wexpect](https://pypi.org/project/wexpect/), which does the job.